Remove part of string starting from right
i'm using T-SQL and i want to remove part of a string, starting from the right side until (and including) the first hyphen, for example:
OBE-7777-1234   --> OBE-7777
but it could also include just one hyphen:
66ATR-258    --> 66ATR
i tried using SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX, LEN but i can't quite get there
Thanks in advance for your help
        select SUBSTRING(myfield, CHARINDEX('-', myfield) + 1, LEN(myfield) 
              - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(myfield)) 
              - CHARINDEX('-', myfield))
              from mytable
where myfield = 'OBE-7777-1234'

